# Crystal + Amber: "cannot find -lsqlite3 (this usually means you need to install the development package for libsqlite3)"

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

After running [the command to install Ubuntu dependencie](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/All-required-libraries)s, I am still receiving the following error when trying to run a `shards build`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3 (this usually means you need to install the development package for libsqlite3)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz (this usually means you need to install the development package for libz)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer was somewhat in the error message, though not immediately obvious:

`cannot find -lsqlite3 (this usually means you need to install the development package for libsqlite3)`

which, in fact, meant that I needed to install `libsqlite3-dev`.

Similarly:

`cannot find -lz (this usually means you need to install the development package for libz)`

in fact meant that I needed to install `libz-dev`.

With these dependencies installed, `shards build` completed successfully. So, the pattern appears to be adding `-dev` to the end of the recommended library's name.